# How to send an array to a web api with Angular2 and Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I can't manage to send an array to a web api with Angular2. In my Typescript I'm calling the api with this:

```
apiData(command?: string | null, array?: string[] | null): Observable<void> {
    //let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/Data/command?";
    let url_ = "/api/Data/command?";

    if (command !== undefined)
        url_ += "command=" + encodeURIComponent("" + command) + "&";
    url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

    //const content_ = JSON.stringify(array);

    if (array !== undefined)
        array && array.forEach(item => { url_ += "array=" + encodeURIComponent("" + item) + "&"; });



    let options_: any = {
        //data: content_,
        method: "post",
        headers: new Headers({
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        })
    };
```

And the Api looks like this:

```
    [Produces(typeof(void))]
    [HttpPost("command")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostData(string command, string[] array)
    {
```

When using the above example the api receives the correct amount rows in the array but they are all "[object Object]".

If I use JSON.stringify(array) and send it through as Data: (commented out in my example) the web api only gets an empty string. The array I'm sending through is JSON.

This approach worked in Angularjs but for some reason I can't get this to work.

Comment: the Response '[objectObject]', where you are getting? in component level or in view?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Post method in your service.

```
constructor(private _http: Http){}
apiData(command?: string | null, array?: string[] | null): Observable<void> {

// your code
return this._http.post(url, array, options)
.map(
   // response logic
)
.catch(
  // exception handling
);
}
```

your component:

```
constructor(private _service : AboveServiceComponent)
getStatusofSentData(){
this._service.subscribe(
res => {
// get response
},
err => {
// handle error if any
}
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use like this.

```
apiData(command?: string | null, array?: string[] | null): Observable<void> {
  //let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/Data/command?";
  let url_ = "/api/Data/command?";

  if (command !== undefined)
      url_ += "command=" + encodeURIComponent("" + command) + "&";
  url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

  //const content_ = JSON.stringify(array);

  let data: any = { command: url_, array: array};

  let options_: any = {
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    method: "post",
    headers: new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    })
};
```